# Visual studio 2013 server explorer procedure find tool

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and in our project we are using more than 1600  store procedures. So when I expanding the store procedure from (View -> server explorer->select Database->expand stored procedure)server explorer, It is very difficult to find the store procedure, do we have any tools or other option to find the store procedure easier?

I am trying to search google but I can't found any tools or other options

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8peN.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can view your stored procedure through ServerExplorer either in Visual stored or using Management Studio.

As the stored procedures are available within the ServerExplorer you have no other option rather waiting for them to get opened via ServerExplorer.

> This is same as can we view tables without using server explorer

**using .dbml** :

Any changes you make in SQL server are not auto-synched to your .dbml file. If you make table or stored procedure changes you need to delete them from the .dbml file and add them again.

Comment: I could find through serverExplorer while Drag into the .DML file

Comment: Any changes you make in SQL server are not auto-synched to your .dbml file. If you make table or stored procedure changes you need to delete them from the .dbml file and add them again.